# How to save an AST generated by ANTLR

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

I have successfully generated an AST using ANTLR in python but I cannot figure out for the life of me how I can save this for later use. The only option I have been able to figure out is to use `tree.toStringTree()` method, but the output of this is messy and not overly convenient or easy to work with.

How do I save it and what format would be best/easiest to work with and be able to visualise and load it in in the future?

**EDIT:** I can see in the java documentation there is a DotGenerator() to generate a DOT file of the tree, but I can't find a way to do anything like this in python.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Are you looking to just visualize the parse tree? Or are you wanting to later reload the Antlr parse tree data structure so you can use the Antlr runtime to make changes to it, or to run a visitor or listener on the tree? Also, Antlr4 does not generate an AST. It generates a parse tree. Are you calling `toStringTree(ruleNames)` or `toStringTree()`?

Comment: Visualising it would be a bonus, but mainly I need to output it in a way I can reload it and make changes. I was using ```toStringTree()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a serializer/deserializer of the parse tree. Serialization was previously addressed in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562061/serialization-of-antlr-parsetree). It isn't supported in the runtime (ASAIK) because it is not useful: one can reconstruct the tree very quickly by re-parsing the input. Even if you want to change the tree using a transformation, you can replace the nodes in the tree with sub-trees with node types that don't even exist in your parser, print out the tree, then re-parse to reconstruct the tree with the parse types for your grammar. It only makes sense if parsing with semantic analysis is very slow. So, you should consider the problem carefully.

However, it's not difficult to write a crude serializer/deserializer that does not consider "off-channel" content like spacing or comments. This C# program (which you could adapt to python) is an example that reconstructs the tree using the [grammars-v4/sexpression.g4](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/sexpression) grammar for a target grammar [arithmetic.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/arithmetic). Using `toStringTree(rule-names)`, the tree is first serialized into a string. (Note, `toStringTree()` without the parser rule names is difficult to read, that is why I asked.) Then, the s-expression is parsed and a bottom-up reconstruction is performed using an Antlr visitor. Since `toStringTree()` does not mark the parse tree leaves with the type of the token (e.g., to distinguish between a number versus a symbol), the string is lexed to reconstruct the value. It also uses reflection to create the correct parse tree node type.

Outputting a Dot graph for the parse tree is also easy, which I included in the program, [using a top-down recursive visitor](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/blob/dbf46256416be6562be5b3578595dff73abea10f/sexpression/Program.cs#L32). Here, the recursive function outputs each edge to a child for a particular node. Since each node name has to be unique (it's a tree), I added the pre-order tree number for the node to the name.

--Ken